# Storyboard segue issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm developing an iPhone app in Xcode 4 and i'm using storyboard. I am using a single view application. I have a segue that connects my home page (controlled by my view controller class ViewController) and another view that has a UIImageView in it. On the home page the user is able to pick an image and then the UIImageView on the other view would show that image. I thought at first that the UIImageView would still be on the ViewController class but when i push the second view it shows that it is a UIView and i can't change that. I believe that I have to create another class to handle the second view but I don't know how to do that. Secondly i do not know how to connect that class with the view and then have the segue work. Am i on the right track or am I totally wrong. Help Please... Thank you.
PS Now that I typed this out i looked at some of the similar questions and i'm reading a whole lot about this prepareForSegue method. Is that what is used to segue between view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to address your question is a good hand on tutorial on Storyboards.  Try this two parts [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) series.